# Adding another subdirectory based application to a Zend Framework subdirectory based application

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

I have a php web app created with the zend framework. The document root is public_html and the hosting provider will not let me change it to the public_html/public subdirectory.  That wasn't a problem as I found the following .htaccess file which allowed my app to work with the following directory layout:

```
public_html/public
public_html/application
public_html/application/controllers
```

etc..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Now I have a new requirement that I need to run another web app from a different subdirectory under public_html for the same domain, lets call it other, i.e. public_html/other

I've tried modifying the .htaccess file to redirect any requests containing "other" to the public_html/other subdirectory, but it always results in a 500 system error, for example if I add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/other/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /other/$1
```

Everything breaks and all requests result in a 500 system error.  Any suggestion on how to craft the rewrite rules to make this happen?

Comment: why don't you keep your zend files outside of the public directory?

Comment: My zend files are outside the public directory.  The public directory only contains my index.php file, as well as .js and img files.  All other code(models, views, controllers, etc) are under the application directory.

Comment: Spackman I meant outside of public_html

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you mean: public_html/../application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^other - [L]
```

should do it.

Comment: Well, that was simple.  Thank you!